# Lambda funcionality works from its own "test" button, but it doesn´t triggering it from API Gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

The function simply inserts a new column on a DynamoDB´s table. I can verify it works by clicking the "test" button in the lambda function tab (it responds with a `200`), but it returns an error when I attach it to an API Gateway´s POST Request, using the "test" button too, in this case the test button of the API Gateway´s method test tab.

This are the errors:

**Response Body**

{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}

**Response Headers**

```
{"x-amzn-ErrorType":"InternalServerErrorException"}
```

**Logs**

```
Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key site in the item.
```

Here´s the code of the lambda function:

```js
function response( message) {
  return message
}

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
   
    let scanningParameters = {
        Item: {
            "site":event.site
           
        },
        TableName: 'Galleries'
    }
    
     return docClient
    .put(scanningParameters)
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }
    })
   
}
```

However I don´t get why is asking for a key since from the lambda tab it does insert the column in the table correctly. **Here is another function which does work** in API Gateway too and the schema in absolutely the same:

```js
function response( message) {
  return message
}

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'eu-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
   
    let scanningParameters = {
        Item: {
            "email":event.email
        },
        TableName: 'Users'
    }
    
     return docClient
    .put(scanningParameters)
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
        return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    }
    })
   
}
```

Edit: I just solved it by unchecking the check of "Use Lambda Proxy integration" in the integration request tab

Comment: Can you also please show us the console view/API gateway configuration where you specify the route to the Lambda function?

Comment: Mmm, I´m not sure if I know what you refer too, you mean the method request settings?

Comment: Something like that. I can't describe the exact screen, but that will be part of yes. Also the screen where you can select how you proxy the request and what parameters/headers to pass will also be useful.

Comment: @xinkecf35 Oh man I just sort it out by checking those other tabs by some reason in the other example that it worked the "proxy integration" check, it was unchecked. In this case I had checked it. Once I unchecked it worked. Funny enough I thought this check was neccesary to lambda functions to work from API Gateway.

Comment: That's good to hear :-)

Comment: Also, you may want to add your solution to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Unchecking the "Use Lambda Proxy integration" check box fixed the issue.

Comment: can you plz share aws console screenshot for it as I am also facing the same issue but not able to find where this option is

Comment: Ok Found it and unchecked but still getting     "message": "Internal server error"

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing dynamic params queryParams or pathParams,Then you need to use the Proxy integration and return in following way.

```
return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(response)
    }
```

I was facing this error when i was returning in following way

```
  return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: message,
        timeStamp: new Date().toISOString()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to disable the default enabled button named as `Lambda proxy integration` and note written as `Send the request to your Lambda function as a structured event.` and where you can find this button is here,

first goto aws gateway portal then `apis` search your api in list click on it then it must have opened the `resources` ok then below `create resources` you see tree stuctured of your apis here third one Nothing but the method type, click on it for me its `ANY` in uppercase written for me, it will open flow diagram architecture of your api call, below you see navigation bar with options `Method Request|integration request|Integration responses|Test` select `Integration request` and click on edit and boom just disable this `Lambda proxy integration` field and just save now try to Test your api gateway Must working for you by now

[image]